# Java String import java.lang.String

Tags: java, string

When I use `String` in Java do I need to import `java.lang.String`?
Or I can simply use it?

Is `String` imported by default? 
I am using Eclipse and as I know they use another compiler that Java does.
What is the standard way?

Comment: java.lang.* is automatically imported.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073680/why-autoimport-only-java-lang-package

Comment: you don't need to import  java.lang.String

Comment: This question could have been easily avoided...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `java.lang.*` is imported by default.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import anything from `java.lang`. It is imported by default. Everything in there is available without a need to explicitly import anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to formally import java.lang.String .. would represent being "overly redundant" when reading code.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Java classes import all java.lang classes. It's pretty rare to see Java code that explicitly imports java.lang.String.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is imported. use :`String [name] = "[value]";`