# Java Set / Collections issue

Tags: java, collections, set

I'm just starting out with Java and have some fairly basic questions about sets.  I want to create a class called DirectedGraph which has two attributes, a set of vertices and a set of edges.  What would be the best data structure to use for these sets?  It seems Java has several implementations of sets and I would probably just want to use the most basic, featureless kind.

Also, when I try to set the attributes `vertices` and `edges` I get errors like "Set cannot be resolved by a type" or "Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete Reference Type".  Here is some code along with other things I tried commented out:

```
import java.util.Collections;

public class DirectedGraph {
    private Set<> vertices;

    // here are some other guesses that also didn't work:
    // private Set<int[]> vertices;
    // private Set<Integer> vertices;
    // private Set<Integer> vertices = new HashSet<Integer>();
}
```

What is going on with these errors?

Edit:

And if I wanted a constructor that took no arguments but initialized the `vertices` and `edges` sets as empty, how would I do this?

Comment: You are just missing the import. `import java.util.Set`

Comment: Thanks, and I need to use Integer rather than int?  I had tried importing java.util.Set before, but I guess I was using the wrong code inside the class when I did that.

Comment: @Tunaki I added another question about how to initialize empty sets.  If you wanted to move your comment to an answer with or without an answer to this part I'd accept it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/why-can-java-collections-not-directly-store-primitives-types

Comment: Collections can only hold reference types. Not primitive types. Integer is a reference type, int[] is a reference type, but int is a primitive type. To initialize an empty, mutable set, you can use `new HashSet<>()` or `new TreeSet<>()` (or any other set implementation you desire to use). For an immutable empty set, use `Collections.emptySet()`. All your questions are covered by the Java tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/ and by the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: @JBNizet If I use something like `this.vertices = new HashSet<>();` in the DirectedGraph constructor I get an error that HashSet cannot be resolved to type and it doesn't go away when I use `HashSet<Integer>()`.  Any idea as to what's going on?

Comment: @dsaxton Read my answer carefully. Every class outside of `java.lang` needs to be imported. `HashSet` is one of them ;).

Comment: And read the tutorial aboput packages as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html. This is basic stuff, that your Java text book should cover.

Comment: It still says HashSet cannot be resolved to a type even with `import java.util.HashSet`.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not using a textbook, just kind of learning haphazardly by web searches and guessing.  Any suggestions for good books?

Comment: I've learnt Java 18 years ago, so, not really. The online Java tutorial is not bad, and they're being kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the import statement for the `Set` class. [Every class outside of the `java.lang` package needs to be explicitely imported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2073680/1743880).

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set; // <-- needs to import Set to use it

public class DirectedGraph {
    private Set<> vertices;

    // here are some other guesses that also didn't work:
    // private Set<int[]> vertices;
    // private Set<Integer> vertices;
    // private Set<Integer> vertices = new HashSet<Integer>(); // <-- this would need "import java.util.HashSet" to compile
}
```

All of your guesses are correct. [You can't use a primitive type here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2504959/1743880) but you can use `int[]` (which is not a primitive type, it is an Object that is an array of `int`s) and `Integer` (which corresponds the class `java.lang.Object`).