# java.lang package is available to every java program by default

Tags: java

**java.lang** package is available for every java program by default.

1. Why?

Ans: The Java standard libraries include **java.lang** package by default, which contains a number of components that are used very commonly in Java programs. Java is useless without much of the functionality in **java.lang**, that's why **java.lang** is implicitly imported by the compiler for all programs.

2. How does it happen?
3. If I want to create such package which will auto import like **java.lang** package & will be available for every java program then how to do it?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073680/why-autoimport-only-java-lang-package

Comment: 1. Do you really want to type `java.lang.String because = "Why do we want to do this";`? 2. The compiler adds a `java.lang` import 3. Write your own language.

Comment: "Own language" seems a bit overkill, a maybe a [javac-compiler-plugin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/Plugin.html) is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will R&D on javac-complier-plugin.