# Why don't we import java.lang package?

Tags: java, oop

In java we import packages to the classes.when we accessing some thing from a different package we have to import that package to our working package.like,

- java util.*;
- java io.*;

But we never import java lang package.Why is that?what is the specialty in java lang package.

Comment: It is auto imported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073680/why-autoimport-only-java-lang-package

Comment: @ThilanRavindu your question is entirely reasonable: it is non-obvious why it should be so. It has just been asked many times before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because:

> Code in a compilation unit ... automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package `java.lang`.

Source: [Java Language Specification #7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html)

Comment: Translation: "just because".  Hmmm ....

Comment: @Rick Translation: because that's the way they designed it, and here is the JLS citation to prove it. What else were you expecting exactly?

Answer (score -1):

`Java.lang` package is imported by default. If you check the documentation, then you'd see you use mostly half of it blindly.

Documentation: https://www.cs.mun.ca/java-api-1.5/api/java/lang/package-summary.html

Source: http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week4/31.html

Comment: Elliotte  Rusty Harold's text is not a normative reference.